# How do I resolve IMPORTHTML showing error #N/A?

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

N/A error showing on following query:

```
=importhtml("http://www.barchart.com/commodityfutures/Cotton_%232_Futures/CT?search=CT*","table",1)
```

and

```
=Importhtml(A2,"table",1)
```

Also table id is `dt1`.

Comment: @w3dk Yes! its google spreadsheet

Answer (score 2):

On mouse over the cell's top right corner, Google Sheets shows extended error description "Import Internal Error":

[image: Import internal error]

That means that there is an error one the Google side. You could report it by clicking in Help > Report a problem Google Sheets' menu and filling out and submitting the feedback form.

Answer (score 0):

The site offers free API service: http://www.barchartondemand.com/freemarketdataapi.php

You might want to try signing up and getting XML feed instead.